# Ищу аналог madExcept для перехвата исключений и отправке логов по почте

Tags: delphi, поиск-библиотек

Есть бесплатные аналоги или как можно перехватить все Exception  в программе? Хочу генерить лог и отправлять его на почту.

Comment: Я бы посоветовал из абсолютно бесплатного https://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help:JclHookExceptions , но там нужно будет кодить, в отличие от MadExcept и EurekaLog. Полноценным ответом сие оформить не могу, поскольку не приходилось использовать.

Answer (score 0):

Если ваше приложение не консольное и использует VCL, то самым простым способом будет воспользоваться событием `Application.OnException`. Сюда попадают все не перехваченные ошибки *из основного потока*. Основной минус - мало информации: тип и сообщение об ошибки.

Задать можно как в коде, так и через компонент *TApplicationEvents*.

Comment: `Сюда попадают все не перехваченные ошибки` - неправда ваша. Сюда попадают только не-перехваченные ошибки, возникшие в ходе обработки сообщений в основном потоке(!) и все не-перехваченные исключения, возникшие в событиях TTimer.OnTimer (! вне зависимости от потока исполнения). Ни одно исключение из дополнительных потоков в это событие не попадет.

Comment: @kami Я допишу про основной поток, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так. Взял за основу JvDebugHandler, там идет запись в лог через StringList. В формирование листа я просто добавил свою строчку. В принципе формируется не плохой отчет, плюс идет до запись при каждом Exception. Советую как бесплатную альтернативу.